# Suggested Equicontinuity Problem

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

My professor has suggested the following equicontinuity problem:

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $C$ be a subset of $C(X)$. If $C$ is compact, then $C$ is closed and bounded (in the metric space $C(X)$). Show that $C$ is also equicontinuous.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @Harald I know that since C is closed and bounded, then C must be contained within some epsilon neighborhood. I also know that since C is compact and X is compact, that every function f element of C is uniformly continuous.  Edit: I think I can say that C is compact, then C is totally bounded.

Comment: Yes, but when I said contrapositive, I meant this: Assume that $C$ is *not* semicontinuous, and try to prove that then it is not compact. (Note that I haven't actually tried doing this, just that I think it may be fruitful. Well, actually I *did* try it, but without writing anything down, so there may be a mistake in my argument.)

Comment: I wrote semicontinuous, but meant equicontinuous, clearly. I just missed the edit deadline …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you only have to prove that $C$ is bounded if it is compact since in every metric space, compact sets are closed.
Also, I guess that you have provided $C(X)$ with the uniform norm.

Assume, to get a contradiction, that $C$ is not bounded. Then there's a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ such that $\Vert f_n\Vert_\infty \geq n$. Since the sequence is infinite and $C$ is compact, it has limit point, say $f$. (Wich we may assume to be a limit taking a subsequence if necessary). Note that there exist an $N$ such that $\Vert f-f_n\Vert _\infty <1$ for $n\geq N$ and this implies that $ \Vert f_n\Vert_\infty -1<\Vert f\Vert_\infty$. Then, $f$ i s not bounded and this is a to contradiction to the fact that $f\in C(X)$ since if were continuous, it will be bounded since $X$ is compact.

Now, as you have commented in a comment, since every  function in $C$ it is uniformly continuous. Using this, given $\varepsilon>0$, consider the open balls $B_f= \{g\in C: \Vert g-f\Vert_\infty<\varepsilon/4\}$ an the open cover $U=\{B_f:f\in C\}$. Since $C$ is compact there exist a finite set of functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ such that $\{B_{f_1}, \ldots, B_{f_n}\}$ is a cover of $C$. Since each of this functions is uniformly continuous on $X$ to each $f_n$ there's associated a $\delta_n$ such that
$$
d(f_n(x),f_n(y ))<\varepsilon/4 \quad \mathrm{if}\quad d(x,y)<\delta_n
$$
Take $\delta=\min\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}(\delta_k)$. 
Can you show that this $\delta$ works for the definition of equicontinuity?

Comment: I don't need to prove that C is bounded if it is compact. I am given that since C is compact, then it is closed and bounded. I need only to prove that since C is compact, then C is equicontinuous.

Comment: If you focus on the last paragraph, I think you will see that this approach works.

Comment: After your last step, do I then need to apply the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea

Comment: Thank you, Brandon. I also posted another problem on equicontinuity yesterday that I would also appreciate some help with. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637709/equicontinuity-problem

Comment: I am having trouble getting the triangle inequality to work out. What would be on the right side of the inequality?

Comment: Note that for each $g\in C(X)$ there's an $f_n$ suche that $\Vert f_n-g\Vert_\infty<\varepsilon/3$. Then, for every $x,y$ we have $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq |g(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|+|f_n(y)-f(_n(x)|\leq 2\Vert F_n-g\Vert +|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|$. Note that if we take $d(x,y)<\delta$ the right hand side is less than $\varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

What I wrote in my comment, in more detail: If $C$ is not equicontinuous at $x$, there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there is some $y$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$ and a function $f$ with $|f(y)-f(x)|\ge\varepsilon$. Pick a sequence $\delta_n\to0$ with corresponding $y_n$, $f_n$, and check to see if $(f_n)$ can have a convergent subsequence.